# group of linear functions and metabelian groups

Tags: group-theory, functions

Let $G$ represent the group  of linear functions under composition of the form $x \mapsto ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a\neq0$. Is $G$ a metabelian group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $A$ be a set of functions $x\mapsto x+t$, $t\in\mathbb Q$, $B$ is a set of functions of the form $x\mapsto ax$, $0\neq a\in\mathbb Q$. Then $A,B\leq G$, $A\cong\mathbb{Q}^+$, $B\cong\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $G=A\rtimes B$, i.e. $G=AB$, $A\unlhd G$, $A\cap B=1$. So $A$ - normal abelian subgroup and $G/A\cong B$ - abelian group.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I'm not sure but I think you meant that $A\cong\mathbb{Q}$ considering the addition for rational numbers. Now  is it necessarily to stabilish the isomorphism for $A$? Also we can show directly that $B$ is abelian by considering $(a_1 x)\circ (a_2 x)=(a_2 x)\circ (a_1 x)$.

Comment: @user129118 Yes of course, for Your goals it is not necessarily to proof that $A\cong\mathbb{Q}^+$, and $B\cong\mathbb{Q}^*$. It is enough to show, that $A,B$ abelian. Yes, $\mathbb{Q}^+$ - rationals by addition, $\mathbb{Q}^*$ - group of nonzero rationals by multiplication.